# requestmapping not working. springmvc maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

My request mapping is not working in spring MVC. First page index.jsp loads.
When it redirects to an action the controller is not getting invoked.
Here are my artifacts:

Here is my web.xml:

```
        <web-app>
            <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>

            <listener>
                <listener-class>
                    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
            </listener>

            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.ta.controller" />

            <bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
                </property>
                <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.jsp</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
            <mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        </beans>
```

Here is my Controller class:

```
            @RequestMapping(value ="/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.POST )
            public ModelAndView dashboard(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {

                ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
                view.addObject("name", name);
                return view;
   Below is the Index.jsp

        <form:form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="dashboard">
              <div class="login-wrap">
                <div class="login-html">
                    <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Sign In</label>
                    <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <div class="sign-in-htm">
                            <div class="group">
                                <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                                <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form:form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

This is as per the basic tutorials of spring mvc. Please let me know where things are going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should set init parameters in your spring mvc servlet tag.and they can tell you dispatcherServlet where to find your configurations.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/ApplicationContext-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>                                                                                                                        It was defined as context param anyway i defined as init param and tried, still getting the same issue.

Comment: you should use absolute path , or use the path Relative to your classpath(when your project run ,it will be **projectPath/WEB-INF/classes**)，and I think the second way is better

Comment: The default spring-mvc dispatcher path is WEB-INF directory, the name is [<servlet-name>] - servlet.xml,so configuration should also be available, but I do not know why it is useless to you